# How to extract a specific timeframe from datetime?

Tags: matlab, datetime

**I have the time in datetime format like below. I would like to extract the time from '20-Apr-2020 11:20:10' till '20-Apr-2020 12:40:50'. Do I need it to convert it first to datenumber or I can do it directly here?**

```
Time_datenum={'20-Apr-2020 11:06:00','20-Apr-2020 11:20:10','20-Apr-2020 11:45:30','20-Apr- 
2020 12:07:00','20-Apr-2020 12:35:40','20-Apr-2020 12:40:50','20-Apr-2020 13:07:00'};
Time_datetime = datetime(Time_One,'InputFormat','dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Time_datenum={'20-Apr-2020 11:06:00','20-Apr-2020 11:20:10','20-Apr-2020 11:45:30',...
    '20-Apr-2020 12:07:00','20-Apr-2020 12:35:40','20-Apr-2020 12:40:50','20-Apr-2020 13:07:00'};

% Create a datetime array from a cell array of character vectors.
Time_datetime = datetime(Time_datenum, 'InputFormat', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'Locale', 'en_GB');

% t = datetime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second)
Time_start = datetime(2020, 4, 20, 11, 20, 10);
Time_end   = datetime(2020, 4, 20, 12, 40, 50);

% Extract the time.
Time_extracted = Time_datetime(Time_start <= Time_datetime & Time_datetime <= Time_end);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I needed.